# Is it possible to have different properties for the same model in multi-tenant applications scenario?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant

I have to design a multi-tenant application, I need to have custom fields for each tenant in the same model.

Customer 1 need to use some custom field, Customer 2 need to manage other fields in the same table and so on..

This is an example:
the same table (ticket) has a common (base) field list, then each tenant should be have his additional columns in the model:

I would like to implement a EF Code first .Net Core web application.

```
namespace Models.Base
{
    public class TicketBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public Datetime CreationDate { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Tenant 1

```
namespace Models.Tenant1
{
    public class Ticket : TicketBase
    {

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        public Datetime DateCustomerCall { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Tenant 2

```
namespace Models.Tenant2
{
    public class Ticket : TicketBase
    {

        public string AnotherDescription { get; set; }
        public Datetime AnotherDate { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Is it correct to design the model this way or there are different approaches to this very common problem?

Comment: There is not one-size-fits-all solution for that. It depends very much on how your models differ, how often the requirements change etc.

Comment: Hi, I would like to use this approach https://stackify.com/writing-multitenant-asp-net-core-applications/ or https://benfoster.io/blog/aspnet-core-multi-tenancy-data-isolation-with-entity-framework but it seems they share the same models

Comment: If TicketBase class represents bare bone ticket properties and you are not going to ever instantiate Ticketbase class as an object, then instead of TicketBase class you can consider having those properties as a part of ITicket interface. And let multiple tenant implement ITicket + their additional properties. This will also help you leverage multi tenancy DI injection where you can register tenant specific ticket objects and resolve them in your code, based on tenants through ITicket interface...Just another food for thought for your design.

Comment: Thank you Asif, and How do you would implement it  in .net core EF?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, In SaaS, having a single code base and flexible configuration / extension for mutli-tenancy is the key to success.

To enable custom fields per tenant, the business model will have to have a fixed set base fields. The custom fields will have to be stored by entityid and tenantid in a separate table.

Your tables could look like the ones given below. This model is preferred so that having a generic extension table will result in less scalability and could soon be filled with the data volume as usage goes up.

Ticket

TicketExtn (extension table containing custom fields by tenant and entity)

The `TicketExtn` table will contain fields like

`TicketId
TenantId
FieldId
FieldValue
FieldDataType`

etc
When we try to get the data for the `Ticket` entity, we will also be getting the data from the `TicketExtn` table and be setting the fields in the model.

The BaseModel will look like the one given below

```
public class ExtendedField
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public Guid DataTypeId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Can also be a typed class, this is just for reference
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The field value.</value>
    public string FieldValue { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Incase of using string for fieldvalue, the string to format the value as per the required datatype 
    /// will be provided here.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The field value format string.</value>
    public string FieldValueFormatString { get; set; }
}

public class BaseModel
{
    Dictionary<string, ExtendedField> ExtendedRows { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket : BaseModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

In your services layer, there will be logic to fill these extended rows. Its better to have the logic for the filling up of the extended rows generic so that for any number of entities, this logic can be re-used.

HTH

Comment: Thank you Saravanan, this is the actual implementation the application has. (somet hink like https://github.com/dubeaud/bugnet), I would like to know if there is a way to have a simplest way to deal with entities, viewmodels and views in a mvc scenario. I'd like to have something like Ticket.MyPropertyTenant1 = "value"  without handle with  disctionaries, data types etc.